# could this be a F# 6 indexer bug?

Tags: f#

let's consider this code:

```
type T =
    {
        a: int
    }    

let d =
    [
        "a", [{a = 0}; {a = 1}; {a = 2}]
        "b", [{a = 3}; {a = 4}; {a = 5}]
    ] |> Map
```

If I want to access the data with a = 0:

```
d.["a"].[0].a  <- works
d["a"].[0].a   <- now works with F#6
d["a"][0]      <- returns {a = 0}
```

but

```
d["a"][0].a    <- typecheck error This value is not a function and cannot be applied.
```

if I wrap the expression in parenthesis:

```
(d["a"][0]).a  <- it works
```

Is this expected, or could it be a F#6 parsing bug?

Comment: I agree that this seems fishy.

Comment: If there isn't one I think you should create an issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp . To me it looks it should work.

Comment: @Justanothermetaprogrammer I did

Answer (score 2):

In the end, this was done for compatibility reasons; see the reply by Don Syme:

https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/12549#event-5840475607

A request to allow this notation was posted and seems approved.

https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/1109